# Unable to get particular rows from database that match conditions in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am currently having problem getting data from my database that has variable set as greater than 50 and time is set as today's date.

here's my code:

```
 public function getAllbananaindoor($today){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM garden WHERE humid >? AND temp=?");
        $hum = '50';
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$hum, $today);
        $stmt->execute();
        $students = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $students;
    }
```

But if i remove one of the temp=? or humid>? then it works but not with together. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `i` for `integer` instead of `s` for `string` :

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii",$hum, $today);
```

Comment: okay. thanks i really forgot to add i. also, how can i run this : $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM garden WHERE humid >? AND time=? AND ? =>humid => ?"); humid has integer less than and greater than.

Comment: it should be `>=` not `=>`